# Android ScanDit add text view (in XML) to cropped scan view

Tags: android, xml, barcode, barcode-scanner

i want to use Scandit barcode library in my app. I followed the tutorial and i decided to use cropped scan view to get the barcode. In remaining space of the view i would like add text view where i want to display some informations. Everything defined in separated layout xml view (no programatically);

I tried to use Scandit SDK documentation, but without luck. Could somebody tell me, how can i do this?

Thanks for any help.

[image: Preview]

Comment: Which tutorial? Its really unclear what is your requirement. What does `Everything defined in separated layout xml view (no programatically);` this means??

Comment: In sample SDK app, is cropped view and content of this view created programatically in Main Activity (without using the separated layout). I would like to have separated layout for activity divided to 2 parts (scan view and textview)

Comment: is the Scanview would be some image or what ??

Comment: And it would be good if you can show the main activity.

Comment: Scandit in not image, is it camera view which scans barcodes. In their example is the camera view created programatically as new layer over the main activity without appending camera view into the separated layout. And i want to create stand alone layout, where i can add in XML file textview or something else. This is the matter of the Scandit SDK.

Comment: hmmmmm i dont know scandit. What is this? Should i search for the tutorial by myself? How do we know what is there in `MainActivity` what code they have? How can we suggest what should do without knowing what the code is ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the layout like in your demo pic you can use this layout change it as it suits your requirement. This will provide the layout you want to achieve. And you can set this layout in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method of the activity using the method `setContentView(R.layout.scanbar.xml);`. Here scanbar.xml is the layout described below.

scanbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_about_us"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/some"
        android:text="some text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```